# Weird behavior for the loss function while training a neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on constructing a model to do some regression at the end. Therefore, I trained a convolutional neural network at the beginning. The conv net was the encoder in a variational autoencoder. after training the VAE, I removed the decoder and used it with GRU. Then I trained a gated recurrent network on top of the convolutional neural network, that is, the encoder. Hence, the features of the images after the conv net were fed into the recurrent neural network. After training the recurrent neural network alone "*On top of the conv net*", I did a fine tuning to train the whole network combined.

Here is the loss function that I have achieved so far.

[image]

As we can see from the above graph, the loss was decreasing and about to converge, but then has some weird behavior at the end.

I would like to know the reasons for this behavior.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: is this the loss on the train or validation set?

Comment: This is on the train set